Unable to eliminate a warning message on my Azure DevOps pipeline
I will begin by saying - this issue is not preventing my pipeline from running correctly, it runs, as expected - it even handles all my artifact creation and prep (so I can use a release to drop the bits when needed), again; I am not doing anything out of the ordinary, just building a 3 sites and deploying them to IIS on a webserver.
Our Pipelines list in Azure DevOps is showing an odd error message that is not giving up it's secrets.  So I made some changes to my Azure-Pipelines.yml file that controls the build/deployment etc... in Azure Dev Ops.  After I made these changes, I started seeing an error message show up on the top of our Pipelines list.  It states
"Some recent issues detected related to pipeline trigger."
Opening the issue, by clicking the "View Details" button on the right side of this message I see the details (of which there isn't much to speak of).  I see the following...

My YML file was using the task name I put in (which appears to be a predefined task in Azure DevOps, it's been since Cruise Control since I last had to do my own CI setup work, forgive my lack of knowledge).
Here is our YML file - it's pretty basic.  (food for thought... why does it almost seem like there might be some kind of non-printable ASCII character messing up the parsing on this?  I have no earthly idea).
There isn't anything sensitive on this YML file so I didn't even need to redact anything - WYSIWYG.
Anyone else see what I am doing incorrectly on this YML file for Azure?  I will point out the obvious that there are more than one task named things like "DotNetCoreCLI@2",  I will mention that previously we had 2 tasks in our last YML file that used this twice - no issue, so is adding a 3rd the straw that broke the camels back?  It seems completely unintuitive IMHO...
Our old YML file looked like this....
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main
- develop
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  pdxUiProj: 'Priority.Dispatch.UI/Priority.Dispatch.UI.PDS.csproj'
  pdxUiProjNuGetConfig: 'Priority.Dispatch.UI.PDS/NuGet.config'
  
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 8'
  inputs:
    version: 8.0.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
#    arguments: '--runtime win'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(pdxUiProjNuGetConfig)'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'TelerikWithNuGetKey'
    arguments: '-p:TargetFramework=net8.0'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

# Publish projects to specified folder.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Api dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'Priority.Dispatch.Api/Priority.Dispatch.Api.csproj'
    arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Hub dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'Priority.Dispatch.Hub/Priority.Dispatch.Hub.csproj'
    arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Api Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Priority.Dispatch.Api/bin/Release/net8.0/win-x64/publish
    artifactName: Api

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Hub Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Priority.Dispatch.Hub/bin/Release/net8.0/win-x64/publish
    artifactName: Hub

and this is the new one (just added a couple tasks - one to build the website - another to put together the artifact for release.
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main
- develop
- feature/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  pdxUiProj: 'Priority.Dispatch.UI/Priority.Dispatch.UI.PDS.csproj'
  pdxUiProjNuGetConfig: 'Priority.Dispatch.UI.PDS/NuGet.config'
  
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK 8'
  inputs:
    version: 8.0.x

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
#    arguments: '--runtime win'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: '$(pdxUiProjNuGetConfig)'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'TelerikWithNuGetKey'
    arguments: '-p:TargetFramework=net8.0'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $buildConfiguration) --collect "Code coverage"'

# Publish projects to specified folder.
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Api dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'Priority.Dispatch.Api/Priority.Dispatch.Api.csproj'
    arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Hub dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'Priority.Dispatch.Hub/Priority.Dispatch.Hub.csproj'
    arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'CXT integration dotnet publish $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: 'Priority.Dispatch.System.CXTIntegrationApi/Priority.Dispatch.System.CXTIntegrationApi.csproj'
    arguments: '-p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Api Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Priority.Dispatch.Api
    artifactName: PDS Api

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Hub Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Priority.Dispatch.Hub/bin/Release/net8.0/win-x64/publish
    artifactName: PDS Hub

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'CXT Integration API Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Priority.Dispatch.System.CXTIntegrationApi
    artifactName: Cxt Integration```



I don't get how adding a new task doing pretty much the same thing as we are doing for the previous two projects we wanted to include in this build would cause this to start showing that error on the pipelines page, and why would it parse okay, save and even run as expected - yet still show this message?

Thanks In Advance


From the YAML sample, the format should be correct.
The cause of the issue could be that the YAML pipeline is using the wrong yaml file in the different branch by default.
To solve this issue, you need to check the branch where the correct pipeline yaml is located.
Then you can modify the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds in YAML pipeline.
You can check the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds of the pipeline(Navigate to Edit -> Triggers -> Yaml -> Get sources).

If the branch is not correct, you need to modify it to the correct branch.
For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: The pipeline default branch

I checked the Trigger settings and it looks like I am pulling the branch from develop which has the YML you stated it was the correct format.  Like you stated, it all looks correct, and it even works as expected.  It just has that message at the top now (which ruining my OCD's day kind of the same way my Jenkins builds used to when I didn't have the sunchine Icon, it must be perfect so I would manually build it until the clouds went away, I'll do that here too for this... or I can live with it... LOL).  If it's just a bug that might go away in a future patch -I can ignore it.  Thank you Kevin!

@Chase As you said, the pipeline can run fine without issue. I suggest that you can ignore it. It could be a temporary error on Pipeline UI. And you can try to use the same yaml to create a new pipeline to confirm it. It should be no issue in the new pipeline with the same yaml
